# jQuery.Deferred.prototype.then: returns an object with behaviour I don't understand

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I've been having trouble with `jQuery.Deferred.prototype.then`,
so I decided to look at jQuery's test suite to check if I
correctly understand the behaviour of this method.
The test which is most relevant to my problem is the following, from
release 3.2.1:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3.2.1/test/unit/deferred.js#L133-L168

Note:

- The `Deferred` object is rejected on line 153.
- `done` is called on lines 144 and 164.
  I'm not that familiar with QUnit, but it's pretty clear to
  me that the test will fail unless
  the callbacks that are passed to `done` are actually executed.
- The callbacks passed to `done` should be executed if and only if the `Deferred` object
  is resolved, not rejected.
  (That's my understanding of the `Deferred`
  [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/),
  anyway.)

But the above 3 points can't all be correct!

Both calls to `done` are made on an object returned by
`jQuery.Deferred.prototype.then`.  I can explain the
code if I posit that, in the `Promise` object returned by `then`,
the final status is different from the status of the original
`Deferred`.  However, I can find no hint of this in the jQuery
documentation.

To put my question as briefly as possible: when
the code that I have linked to above is executed, are the callbacks
that are passed to `done` executed, and if so, why?

**UPDATE**

Here is the code that I linked to above (with a few comments added to indicate line numbers):

```
QUnit.test( "jQuery.Deferred.then - filtering (fail)", function( assert ) {

        assert.expect( 4 );

        var value1, value2, value3,
                defer = jQuery.Deferred(),
                piped = defer.then( null, function( a, b ) {
                        return a * b;
                } ),
                done = jQuery.map( new Array( 3 ), function() { return assert.async(); } );

        piped.done( function( result ) {   // Line 144
                value3 = result;
        } );

        defer.fail( function( a, b ) {
                value1 = a;
                value2 = b;
        } );

        defer.reject( 2, 3 ).then( null, function() {   // Line 153
                assert.strictEqual( value1, 2, "first reject value ok" );
                assert.strictEqual( value2, 3, "second reject value ok" );
                assert.strictEqual( value3, 6, "result of filter ok" );
                done.pop().call();
        } );

        jQuery.Deferred().resolve().then( null, function() {
                assert.ok( false, "then should not be called on resolve" );
        } ).then( done.pop() );

        jQuery.Deferred().reject().then( null, jQuery.noop ).done(   // Line 164
function( value ) {
                assert.strictEqual( value, undefined, "then fail callback can return undefined/null" );
                done.pop().call();
        } );
} );
```

**UPDATE 2**

It turns out that the behaviour of `then` changed with the release of jQuery 3 in June 2016. According to a
[post](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/)
on the jQuery blog, announcing the new release:

> The resolution state of a Deferred created by .then() is now controlled by
>   its callbacks—exceptions become rejection values and non-thenable returns
>   become fulfillment values. Previously, returns from rejection handlers
>   became rejection values.

The [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) for `then` hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: `then` is called when "deferred object is resolved, rejected", return another `promise`, what is not `rejected` anymore so `done` is fired

Comment: Personally I suggest forgetting that `done()` even exists and just use `then()` and `catch()` since deferreds in jQuery 3 are Promises A+ compliant supposedly

Comment: Please insert the relevant test code directly into your question.  External links to THE code that is relevant to the question have a habit of changing or breaking over time rendering the question worthless as a lasting reference.  The external link is OK to be there as a source of other information, but the core code that the question is about should be IN the question itself.

Comment: @Peter: but the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) for `then` says "If the filter function used is null, or not specified, the promise will be resolved or rejected with the same values as the original", which implies that the `Deferred` and the `Promise` have the same status, i.e. both resolved or both rejected.  Also, check out the second last example in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/), right after "Filter reject value:"; it supports my interpretation. ¶ I'm leaving the computer now, so no more comments from me for some hours.

Comment: @jfriend00: done.

Comment: If you think documentation is not accurate you should open an issue here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues or create a pull request with the changes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Deferred object is rejected on line 153.

This is a pretty horrible test, doing many things at once. There are many deferreds and many promises, some of them completely unrelated to each other.

Notice that on line 153, the `defer` deferred is rejected, which does have a `.fail` callback attached, `.then` callbacks attached (which created `piped`), and more `.then` callbacks attached in line 153 itself.

> done is called on lines 144 and 164. I'm not that familiar with QUnit, but it's pretty clear to me that the test will fail unless the callbacks that are passed to done are actually executed.

No. You must not confuse the deferred `.done` method and QUnit's done callbacks. In fact, there are three QUnit callbacks stored in the `done` array, each of them created by `assert.async()`.

> The callbacks passed to done should be executed if and only if the Deferred object is resolved, not rejected.

Yes, this is exactly what happens. Notice that the `.done` calls in lines 144 and 164 are not made on the rejected `defer` deferred, but rather on the `piped` promise and another anonymous promise created by `.then(null, jQuery.noop)`. Those promises are *not* rejected, they are fulfilled with the result of the onrejected callback that was passed as the second argument to the respective `.then` call.

Comment: About the "three QUnit callbacks stored in the done array": yes, I understood this perfectly.  There was no confusion on my part.  About your last paragraph: this is the answer I needed.  I've added supplementary information to my post, in "UPDATE 2".